# openshift create app ask for passwd

Tags: openshift-origin, openshift-client-tools

all. when I try 'rhc create-app demo python-2.7', I meet an issue not able to check out the git repo. system will ask for the password of the cartridge or something. but in fact I have upload the default key from openshift console.
here is what I have done:

1. install openshift from puppet
2. oo-diagnostics check pass
3. create app 
   [image: the pic show the issue]

then I remove the default files in /root/.ssh and remove the key file from openshift console, and recreate the ssh key, and run rhc setup again to upload key. then create app again, but failed again.

Answer (score 1):

In the Broker Virtual Machine, while running - `oo-register-dns -h node -d domainX.example.com XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -k /var/named/domainX.example.com.key`,
The proxy **XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX** should be your **Node Virtual Machine's IP Address** (as I think most probabily you have used Broker's IP Address. Change accordingly and run this command again,
It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with a different (main) domain name instead of example.com? I think it might be the issue as per [wikipedia explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example.com):

> Example.com, example.net, example.org, and example.edu are second-level domain names reserved for documentation purposes and examples of the use of domain names.

Even if you've masked it with your hosts file or local DNS it still might be confusing the Openshift's DNS.

Comment: thanks, ptrk. But even if I re-deploy openshift using another domain, this issue still exists. When I run rhc setup, it indicated that ssh auth failed as follows:An SSH connection could not be established to test1-demo.demo.local. Your SSH configuration may not be correct, or the application may not be responding.
53df27bb54b2eeaab1000007 (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed).

Comment: Is it the online openshift or have you set up your local platform? Your test1-demo.demo.local domain still looks a bit funny to me, unless it's your own local setup. I'd rather expect something with .rhcloud.com

Comment: yep, it is a local setup using puppet, all-in-one. I follow the official doc in openshift-origin, and just make a simple change of the domain to 'demo.local'. private key is generated in /root/.ssh/id_rsa and the public key is in /var/lib/openshift/$user/.ssh/authorized_key. So what do you think may cause this problem? Any clue about this issue is appreciating~Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you got your ssh forwarding agent (f.i. pageant) up? Looks like it's not sending your key, so the server asks for the password.